# Messaging/Eventing Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I am looking for a messaging/eventing framework that will allow changes in one application to be subscribed to by other applications.  My situation is I have an ASP.NET web application that allows users to perform CRUD operations.  I also have multiple unknown applications that are used to synchronize data in our application with data in a clients application.  What I would like to do is allow our ASP.NET app to send out a notification that Company A has been created.  I would like the client application to be able to "subscribe" to the event from our application.  I basically want to get away from the need to modify our ASP.NET code each time a new client app is needed.  What sort of technologies exist to handle this sort of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out NServiceBus: www.nservicebus.com

Excellent framework for handling communication between different business services.

Comment: Cool, that looks like it might work.  I'll investigate that.  Thanks.